# Moodle unable to insert record into database php

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I have an object which I am trying to insert into a database using Moodle 2.2 LMS

Here is the Object:

```
object(object)#269 (17) { ["username"]=> string(5) "missk" ["password"]=> string(16) "BydPDczdwXumhd3S" ["firstname"]=> string(6) "Khutso" ["lastname"]=> string(7) "Mosehla" ["email"]=> string(18) "mosehlak@gmail.com" ["confirmed"]=> int(1) ["lang"]=> string(2) "en" ["firstaccess"]=> int(1375184781) ["mnethostid"]=> string(1) "3" ["secret"]=> string(15) "wNGTybC3x2rPZHO" ["auth"]=> string(4) "soap" ["profile_field_saicaid"]=> string(8) "20052064" ["profile_field_prefix"]=> string(2) "Ms" ["profile_field_membertype"]=> string(3) "TEE" ["profile_field_ssocountry"]=> string(12) "South Africa" ["profile_field_ssocity"]=> string(14) "KWATHEMA EXT 2" ["profile_field_ssoregion"]=> string(5) "North" }
```

When I try and insert the record using this syntax it fails.

```
$nuser->id = $DB->insert_record('user',$nuser);
```

According to the manual, this is the correct syntax.  I have global $CFG and $DB
The insert simply fails and the script stops at this point.

Comment: Are you trying to insert non-unique values into unique fields? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @RedEyedMonster  all of the records are unique, and I dont get any error messages, if I try and perform a test like if($nuser) I still get no error messages and the script stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your $user object includes profile fields that are not fields within the mdl_user table (such as 'profile_field_ssocity'). $DB->insert_record() will insert a single record so the object used to insert this must have properties which all map onto the table the record is inserted into.

If you need to also store the profile field data then you will need to include a script with the function that is designed to do that:

```
require_once $CFG->dirroot . '/user/profile/lib.php';
profile_save_data($usernew);
```